# Cannot open include file 'afxres.h' in VC2010 Express

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to compile an old project using VS express 2010 but I get this error:

> fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'afxres.h'. from this code

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#include "afxres.h"
```

I have installed Windows SDK already, but without any success.

thanks!

Answer (score 218, accepted):

This header is a part of the MFC Library. VS Express edition doesn't contain MFC. If your project doesn't use MFC you can safely replace `afxres.h` with `windows.h` in your `terrain2.rc`.

Comment: thanks, then i get the error: error RC2104: undefined keyword or key name: IDC_STATIC

Comment: @clamp: that sounds like a Common Control definition. try adding #include <Commctrl.h> as well (and link your program to Comctl32.lib)

Comment: Otherwise IDC_STATIC is defined as -1, so define it yourself if that's the only problem remaining.

Comment: winres.h defines IDC_STATIC so you can likely just #include <winres.h> rather than afxres.h or windows.h.

Answer (score 145):

Had the same problem . Fixed it by installing Microsoft Foundation Classes for C++.

1. Start
2. Change or remove program (type)
3. Microsoft Visual Studio
4. Modify
5. Select 'Microsoft Foundation Classes for C++'
6. Update

[image]

In in the Visual Studio Installer for VS 2022 this may be listed as an individual component: "C++ MFC for latest v143 build Tools (x86 & x64)", but you may need to adapt this for your platform and latest version available.

Comment: This should be marked as answer, all other are workarounds or hacks

Answer (score 43):

Even I too faced similar issue,

fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file 'afxres.h'. from this code

Replacing afxres.h with Winresrc.h and declaring IDC_STATIC as -1 worked for me.
(Using visual studio Premium 2012)

```
//#include "afxres.h"
#include "WinResrc.h"
#define IDC_STATIC  -1
```

Comment: I _have_ MFC installed.  The above hack just tells me that WinResrc.h is not found (I am using VS 2019 Community Edition)

Answer (score 16):

Alternatively you can create your own afxres.h:

```
#ifndef _AFXRES_H
#define _AFXRES_H
#if __GNUC__ >= 3
#pragma GCC system_header
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifndef _WINDOWS_H
#include <windows.h>
#endif

/* IDC_STATIC is documented in winuser.h, but not defined. */
#ifndef IDC_STATIC
#define IDC_STATIC (-1)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also try replace afxres.h with WinResrc.h

Comment: I changed the file to windows.h and WinResrc.h and the message has changed in both cases to another messgaes stating : error RC2104: undefined keyword or key name: IDC_STATIC .. I am just guessing that this IDC_static is defined within th original afxres.h file, but how to resolve this new error ?

Answer (score 6):

managed to fix this by copying the below folder from another Visual Studio setup (non-express)

from
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\atlmfc

to
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc

Answer (score 2):

a similar issue is for Visual studio 2015 RC.
Sometimes it loses the ability to open RC: you double click but editor do not one menus and dialogs.

Right click on the file *.rc, it will open:

[image]

And change as following:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue on VS 2019. My solution was to install C++ MFC library from Individual Components tab. When you open Visual Studio go to Tools->GetToolsAndFeatures->IndividualComponents

Select and install:

- MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (Latest)
- C++ ATL for latest v142 build tools (x86 & x64)
- C++ MFC for latest v142 build tools (x86 & x64)

Answer (score -1):

Had similar issue but the message was shown when I tried to open a project solution. What worked for me was:

TOOLS -> Import and Export Settings...-> Reset all settings