# Cannot open resource file in VS 2015: Can't open include file afxres.h

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I converted my VS 2012 projects to VS 2015 by using the automatic conversion tool. When I try to load a resource file (.rc) it fails with this error:

```
fatal error RC1015: cannot open include file afxres.h
```

Any idea?

Comment: `afxRes.h` is an MFC header. Does your VS 2015 installation include MFC?

Comment: @fxiv You are right, but unfortunately at least VS2010 has put "#include afxres.h" also into rc files for non-MFC console applications, so this dependance comes a bit surprising.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566018/cannot-open-include-file-afxres-h-in-vc2010-express

Answer (score 27):

I have seen the same problem with console applications without `MFC` that where generated with `Visual Studio 2010`.

One solution is to modify the installation of `Visual Studio 2015` to include `MFC`. `MFC` is not installed by default because of it's size. But in my opinion this should only be applied if you have applications that use `MFC`.

If you only need `MFC` for `afxres.h` you can replace

```
#include "afxres.h"
[...]
"#include ""afxres.h""\r\n"
```

with

```
#include "WinResrc.h"
[...]
"#include ""WinResrc.h""\r\n"
```

You might need to add (but you will see that when compiling the resources).

```
#define IDC_STATIC -1
[...]
"#define IDC_STATIC -1""\r\n"
```

As you can see in the rc file one of the sections is `TEXTINCLUDE`. When `Visual Studio`'s resource editor opens the rc file and saves it back to disc it takes this section and puts the text into the section marked with *"Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE [...]"*. So take care to change both places of at least the `TEXTINCLUDE` section so that resource editor can do the rest.

Comment: Great solution! I just falled on the same problem when moving an old VS2013 project to a brand new VS2017 installation without MFC. Replacing afxres with WinResrc unlocked my build.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer](https://community.developers.thomsonreuters.com/questions/8225/fatal-error-rc1015-cannot-open-include-file-afxres.html) on Thomson Reuters website worked for me. Adding for other users:

> You probably need to modify the Visual Studio 2015 setup and add the MFC .
>
> Please close VS2015 and go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Microsoft Visual Studio  -> Change -> Modify -> Add Microsoft Foundation Classes
>
> See the figure below:

[image]

Comment: Fixed the error for me in my VS2019 C++ project on new machine!

Answer (score 2):

I'm using VS 2017 and I didn't need to install MFC.  You can change the header to `#include "winres.h"` instead.  There are other minor changes with the `#if` defines, so I strongly suggest you create a new `.rc` resource file and do an A/B compare to see the differences (it is not much). I just compared the old with the new and migrated the differences.