# When trying to compile c++ project in visual studio 2019 I'm getting error '/ZI' and '/Gy-' command-line options are incompatible how to resolve?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   D8016   '/ZI' and '/Gy-' command-line options are incompatible  UNf F:\test\cl  1

I don't see any error/s in the cpp file and if I'm doing double click on the error in the console window it's not doing anything. I thought double click will show me the place and line with the error.

[image: Error]

Comment: The errors are in your project settings.

Comment: @drescherjm In the link you provided I tried the last bottom answer : Project ➔ Properties ➔ C/C++ ➔ General ➔ Debug Information Format ➔ Program Database (/Zi) but after changing it I'm getting another error the first error gone but than I'm getting another error : Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error RC1015 cannot open include file 'afxres.h'. ss F:\Samsung Galaxy S9\Danny Backup\Recovered data 02-10 18_32_36\1  (D) NTFS\C-Sharp\ss.rc 10

Comment: That is completely unrelated to the topic of this question however it can possibly be related to this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566018/cannot-open-include-file-afxres-h-in-vc2010-express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566018/cannot-open-include-file-afxres-h-in-vc2010-express) perhaps you don't have MFC installed.